# Navigation bar doesn't respond on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, navigation

I'm trying to find out why this doesn't work on iphone but works great on desktop. tried it at crossbrowsertesting.com and it works fine on android phones.. but not on iphone.

http://codepen.io/MarcRay/pen/vmJBn

```
   // Sticky Header
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.main_h').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
        $('.main_h').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});

// Mobile Navigation
$('.mobile-toggle').click(function() {
    if ($('.main_h').hasClass('open-nav')) {
        $('.main_h').removeClass('open-nav');
    } else {
        $('.main_h').addClass('open-nav');
    }
});

$('.main_h li a').click(function() {
    if ($('.main_h').hasClass('open-nav')) {
        $('.navigation').removeClass('open-nav');
        $('.main_h').removeClass('open-nav');
    }
});

// navigation scroll lijepo radi materem
$('nav a').click(function(event) {
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    var offset = 70;
    var target = $(id).offset().top - offset;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target
    }, 500);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Do you mean the nav won't display correctly, or that the buttons in the nav do not work?

Comment: Doesn't display at all on iPhone, tried crossbrowsertesting.com and it works fine on android phones.. but not on iphone..

Answer (score 1):

If what is shown on the Codepen is your full HTML, then the problem most likely lies within the lack of some code in your HTML.

Create a `<head>` and insert `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` into it.

Read more on [setting the viewport - Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/set-the-viewport?hl=en).

Comment: You need to proper  HTML. You are missing many components - the !DOCTYPE, head, etc.

Comment: Codepen adds that automatically to the preview so you don't have too, if you check the frame source in the preview you'll see doctype, head etc.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can do the sticky header effect without using jquery or javascript by using the following excerpt from jquery mobile

> To enable this toolbar feature type, you apply the
>   data-fullscreen="true" attribute and the data-position="fixed"
>   attribute to both the header and footer div elements. The framework
>   will also unset the padding for the content container (.ui-content).